# Grabbing RSS

Tags: php

Доброй ночушки! Недавно узнал о существовании RSS(во я темень, да?); научился с помощью регулярных выражений на PHP разбирать RSS-ленту на болтики и выводить в любом виде на свой сайт(кому нужно, могу поделиться скриптом). Вы не поверите, как это просто - хвала регуляркам. Однако тут встают два вопроса:

1. Вообще правомочно ли сие действо, не нарушаются ли авторские права. По моему мнению, если сайт предоставляет RSS-ленту, значит он заинтересован в распространении своего контента по бескрайним просторам сети.
2. С точки зрения SEO вроде как получаются дубли(триплы и т.д.) контента; поисковики игнорируют, а то и вовсе могут забанить сайт.
    Помогите найти правду, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

RSS — семейство XML-форматов, предназначенных для описания лент новостей, анонсов статей, изменений в блогах и т. п. Информация из различных источников, представленная в формате RSS, может быть собрана, обработана и представлена пользователю в удобном для него виде специальными программами-агрегаторами.

Проще говоря - формат рсс для того и придуман, чтобы его грабить :) А для того, чтобы разобрать rss не нужны регулярки, все уже есть в пхп - xml компонент, например.

Comment: Т.е. я могу спокойно добавлять на свой сайт преобразованные RSS-ленты с других сайтов, не опасаясь за здоровье своего сайта, да и своего тоже?!

Comment: нет, не всегда. Одно дело, если отображается не модифицированная лента, другое дело, если лента парсится и преобразовывается в кучу отдельных статей + вырезаются все копирайты.
Но для уверенности, лучше связаться с админами сайта и обсудить.

Comment: Я где-то читал, что если я на странице делаю ссылку на первоисточник ленты, то авторские права не нарушаются. Так ли это?

Comment: Нужно читать, что пишет сайт, у которого Вы хотите взять новость. Для некоторых просто ссылки достаточно. Некоторые могут и письменное разрешение попросить.